# Eclipse Maven Project with Ear, War Project Nodes

Tags: eclipse, maven, war, ear

I am new to eclipse and maven and I see a project which structure (top nodes in Project explorer) look like

```
>MyProj
>MyProj-ear
>MyProj-war
```

Being new to this tech stack, I am reading about ear and war and I think I understand what they are (enterprise archieve and web archive) but I dont know how to create these.

Say if `MyProj` were a JSF or a REST API project?  How do I create the 2 other nodes below it (`MyProj-ea`r and `MyProj-war`)?

[image]

Comment: You give little information, but this might be a maven multi module project.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I am sorry but I dont know what other information you need?  The question is how to create project MyProj-ear and MyProj-war nodes for project MyProj regardless of what type of project MyProj is (I suggest it could be JSF or whatever).  It is possible that I did not provide enough information as I dont know much about this tech stack, but the question boils down to how to create the structure as explained above.  I hope that clarifies it?  Thank you

Comment: No, it does not clarify anything. I don't know if these projects are Maven or Gradle or anything, what is contained in their build files, how they are structured etc. etc.